# How to make a playlist of videos and Powerpoint presentations?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow, presentations

Is there such a player that can handle this.

I want to project this so that it repeats all the items in the playlist

Comment: Question unclear.

Comment: I take it you have a collection of videos and Powerpoint files that you wish to show in a loop? i.e Video1, Ppt1, Video 2, Video3, Ppt2 and then loop through them endlessly?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe screencast the Powerpoint and splice together with the other vids in something like VirtualDub to make one video which pretty much any player will loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about scripting something to call your video player of choice, and PPS files, in the order you want?
Or embed the videos in PowerPoint in the first place?